# C++ cgi запуск exe файла

Tags: c++, apache, xampp, cgi

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Вот код приложения

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    cout << "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Some text</TITLE></HEAD>\n";
    cout << "<body text='#F2F2F2' link='#FF9900' vlink='#FF9900' alink='#FF9900'>\n";
    cout << "<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1251'>\n";
    cout << "<p style='line-height:100%; margin-left:10%;' align='center'><span style='font-size:14pt;'>Cgi-скрипт на С++.</span></p>\n";

    char comment[256];
    Triangle triangle;
    if(GetEnvironmentVariable(L"QUERY_STRING", (LPWSTR)comment,256))
    {
        cout<<"<p style='line-height:100%; margin-left:10%;'>Вы ввели: "<<comment<<"</p>\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Мой алгоритм действий:
 1. Создал простое C++ приложение, скомпилировал его, получил .exe
    файл и заменил расширение на .cgi
 2. Работаю с XAMPP Apache,разместил данный файл в C:\xampp\htdocs\
 3. Далее обращаюсь к данному файлу через localhost{имя файла}.cgi

Проблема: В результате запуска данного файла почему-то открывается cmd консоль и ничего не происходит, как только закрываю консоль в браузере пишет "Server error"

Answer (score 2):

Вот что за плохая привычка пихать `system("pause")` в конец? убирайте и скорее всего все заработает (именно по этому и открывается консоль)

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили))